# Update a column with the data of another column of another table - 11Gr2

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables:

1. `SPC_DEVICE`
2. `SPC_CALIBRATE`

`SPC_DEVICE` contains a column named `CALIBRATION_DATE`.
 
`SPC_CALIBRATE` contains a column named `CUSER5`.

I would like to copy and replace (overwrite) the data in `CUSER5` with the data from `CALIBRATION_DATE`.

I am using `Oracle 11gR2`.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your fast replies! I just got a little more information for what we are trying to accomplish. I have pulled a report using Crystal Reports and it looks like this:

http://imageshack.com/a/img37/2456/1a8w.png

Our requirement has changed a little since my initial post in the following way:

The query will need to copy the data from the `CALIBRATION_DATE` column to the `CUSER5` column IF the `ID` from `SPC_DEVICE` table matches `SPC_DEVICE_ID` from the `SPC_CALIBRATE` table (similar to the 2nd to last line, although this was entered in manually). If there is no match, then skip and do not copy.

Crystal Reports also shows there is a link between `SPC_DEVICE.ID` and `SPC_CALIBRATE.SPC_DEVICE_ID`.

Again, your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a merge like this:

```
MERGE INTO spc_calibrate
  USING spc_device
    ON (spc_calibrate.spc_device_id = spc_device.id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET spc_calibrate.cuser5=spc_device.calibration_date
```

But you need a link between the tables to be able to do this. (spc_calibrate.id = spc_device.id)

There are a few other merge examples here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g.php

(Actually if your table has only one row, then see Gordon Linoff's answer... I assumed a bit more complex goal.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've added a little more information to the original post. I think you are very close with the query I need for my updated requirement. Please let me know if this helps you in helping me achieve my goal.

Comment: I modified the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes it sound like `spc_calibrate` has only one row.  You don't specify any condition between the two tables, so you can use a query like:

```
update spc_device
    set calibration_date = (select cusers from spc_calibrate where rownum = 1);
```

More typically, there would be a way to relate the rows to each other, something like:

```
update spc_device
    set calibration_date = (select cusers
                            from spc_calibrate
                            where cusers.devicenum = spc_device.devicenum
                           );
```

Comment: @LajosVeres no it won't! It leaves as such. OP wants to update everything!

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I don't understand why. The inner query will return with a null or not?

Comment: @LajosVeres . . . If there is no match, the `calibration_date` will be set to `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've added a little more information to the original post. Please let me know if this helps you in helping me achieve my goal.